# takePicture() with cameraOverlayView

Tags: swift

I'm using cameraOverlayView to create a custom camera. However, I'm not sure how to make the button shoot the photo. The Apple Docs say `takePicture()` is the function to use. But it does not compile:

Neither attempt works:

```
let shootPicture = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Camera, target: self, action: takePicture())

let shootPicture = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Camera, target: self, { action -> Void in
            takePicture()
        })
```

#### Updated Attempt:

```
let shootPicture = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Camera,  style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "takePicture")

// separate function
func takePicture() {
        imagePicker.takePicture()
}
```

Still getting syntax error: `missing argument for parameter 'landscapeImagePhone' in call`

But when i add `landscapeImagePhone: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Camera`, I get "extra argument 'landscapeImagePhone' in call"

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stuck on this:

#### Set Bar Item:

```
let shootPicture = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Camera,  target: self, action: "takePicture")
```

#### Create Function

```
func takePicture() {
    imagePicker.takePicture()
}
```